# count special characters from string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```
var temp = "/User/Create";
alert(temp.count("/")); //should output '2' find '/'
```

i will try this way

```
// the g in the regular expression says to search the whole string 
// rather than just find the first occurrence
// if u found User -> var count = temp.match(/User/g);
// But i find '/' char from string
var count = temp.match(///g);  
alert(count.length);
```

u can try here http://jsfiddle.net/pw7Mb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to escape the slash in regex literals:

```
var match = temp.match(/\//g);
// or
var match = temp.match(new RegExp("/", 'g'));
```

However, that could return `null` if nothing is found so you need to check for that:

```
var count = match ? match.length : 0;
```

---

A shorter version could use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), which returns the parts between the matches, always as an array:

```
var count = temp.split(/\//).length-1;
// or, without regex:
var count = temp.split("/").length-1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Enter a regular expression using the escape character: (\)

```
var count1 = temp1.match(/\//g);
```